# Calling a resource from one localhost flask app into another localhost app

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I was wondering if its possible to call a `localhost url` hosted on a flask app from another flask app (also running on localhost but on a different port). I currently have a simple flask app that shows a single image inside its html. The code is the following:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='image1.png')}}" alt="Image 1" height="100" width="100" />
</body>

</html>
```

I run it on `localhost:5001` and it runs absolutely fine. That is I see a single image inside the browser.

Once I get this running within a browser, I open a second app that references this `url` in the form:

`<img src="http://localhost:5001/"/>`

inside `index.html`. This app is then run on `localhost:5000`

However, the image inside the second app doesn't show, even though I can see the domain for the image running just fine when I load `localhost:5001` inside the browser. I understand I could do this simply within one app if I just wanted to show the image (by having the image resources inside one app), but I need to do something like this to test the certificates for separate domains, each one hosting a different image.

I was wondering is something like this possible. If so, what would be the best way to approach it, and if the way I am doing is not correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="http://localhost:5001/"/>
```

The above is invalid, because you're loading the root of that page which returns the HTML.

You ought to reference it as something like:

```
<img src='http://localhost:5001/static/image1.png' />
```

If this doesn't work then load up the working image again, and right click to view in a new tab, noting the correct URL and substitute it here.